# Is the Creative Sound Blaster X-FI Surround 5.1 SB1090 USB sound card supported in Linux?

Tags: linux, audio, drivers

And to what extent does this card have support in Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It exists, though the newer the better as far as this is concerned. The methods of getting it working in Ubuntu 8 & 9 were kludgey, but worked. Strictly speaking, there is driver support. Whether or not the sound applications can use it may be another story.

Comment: Since there's driver support, shouldn't alsa provide the required abstraction for the sound applications so they can use it?

Comment: @Neil For Alsa-using applications that would be the case. The trick appears to be stereo vs 5.1 support, the support for that is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Mine worked (tested on ubuntu 10.04 & 10.10 ). But to get multichannel it needs to be connected when the computer is being powered on.
I have issues also - mine would shut off during 30-90 min. of playback. 
During driver initialization it sends a spike to the amplifier. Looks like the firmware/hardware/software is not doing well to prevent it. 
Don`t know yet why.